# Parse nested JSON file, take out specific attributes and create .txt files out of it

Tags: python, json, attributes, txt

So I am having here one big JSON file which looks like this:

```
data = {
    "Module1": {
        "Description": "",
        "Layer": "1",
        "SourceDir": "pathModule1",
        "Attributes": {
            "some",
        },
        "Vendor": "comp",
        "components":{
            "Component1": {
               "path": "pathToCom1",
               "includes": [
                   "include1",
                   "include2",
                   "include3",
                   "include4",
                   "include5"
               ]
               "generated:" "txt"
               "memory:" "txt"
               etc
            },
            "Component2":{
               "path": "pathToCom2",
               "includes": [
                   "include1",
                   "include2",
                   "include3",
                   "include4",
                   "include5"
               ]
               "generated:" "txt"
               "memory:" "txt"
               etc
            }
        }
    },
    "Module2": {
        "Description": "",
        "Layer": "2",
        "SourceDir": "pathModule2",
        "Attributes": {
            "some",
        },
        "Vendor": "comp",
        "components":{
            "Component1": {
               "path": "pathToCom1",
               "includes": [
                   "include1",
                   "include2",
                   "include3",
                   "include4",
                   "include5"
               ]
               "generated:" "txt"
               "memory:" "txt"
               etc
            },
            "Component2":{
               "path": "pathToCom2",
               "includes": [
                   "include1",
                   "include2",
                   "include3",
                   "include4",
                   "include5"
               ]
               "generated:" "txt"
               "memory:" "txt"
               etc
            }
        }
    },
    "Module3": {
        "Description": "",
        "Layer": "3",
        "SourceDir": "path",
        "Attributes": {
            "some",
        },
        "Vendor": "",
    },
    "Module4": {
        "Description": "",
        "Layer": "4",
        "SourceDir": "path",
        "Attributes": {
            "some",
        }
    }
}
```

Then I filter only ones that have field "Vendor" == "comp" with:

```
data = {k: v for k,v in data.items() if v.get("Vendor") == "comp"}
```

And after that I filter out and get final output:

```
Module1 pathModule1 [('Component1', 'pathToCom1', ['include1', 'include2', 'include3', 'include4', 'include5']), ('Component2', 'pathToCom2', ['include1', 'include2', 'include3', 'include4', 'include5'])]
Module2 pathModule2 [('Component1', 'pathToCom1', ['include1', 'include2', 'include3', 'include4', 'include5']), ('Component2', 'pathToCom2', ['include1', 'include2', 'include3', 'include4', 'include5'])]
```

code for this:

```
for k,v in data2.items():
    components = [(comp_name, comp_data["path"], comp_data["includes"]) for comp_name, comp_data in v["components"].items()]
    print(k, v["SourceDir"], components)
```

Now next thing that I have to do, as final output -> create in folder some .txt files which will be named as Module name, and contain paths to it's components, like this:

Module1.txt should contain only paths to it's components, so

```
Module1.txt has inside:
pathToCom1
pathToCom2

Module2.txt with:
pathToCom1
pathToCom2
```

And also, includes should be stored inside of corresponding .txt files, so we would have at the end name of the Component, and it's "includes" fields, so we would have:

```
Component1.txt with inside:
 include1
 include2
 include3
 include4
 include5

Component2.txt with inside:
 include1
 include2
 include3
 include4
 include5
```

EDIT:

So I have managed to get this, code is:

```
for k,v in data.items():
    components = [(comp_name, comp_data["path"], comp_data["includes"]) for comp_name, comp_data in v["components"].items()]
    with open(components_path+k+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i,n in v['components '].items():
            path_to_write = n['path'] 
            f.write(path_to_write+'\n')
        f.close()
        for i,n in v['components'].items():
            with open(path_to_includes+i+'.txt', 'w') as f:
                includes_to_write = n['includes'] 
                f.write(str(includes_to_write)+'\n')
            f.close()
```

Now the only problem is that I get includes as one line:

['include1', 'include2', 'include3', 'include4'..]

```
I need them to be:
 include1
 include2
 include3
 include4
 include5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally have managed to get this working, here is the code might help someone someday:

```
for k,v in data.items():
    components = [(comp_name, comp_data["path"], comp_data["includes"]) for comp_name, comp_data in v["components"].items()]
    with open(components_path+k+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i,n in v['components '].items():
            path_to_write = n['path'] 
            f.write(path_to_write+'\n')
        f.close()
        for i,n in v['components'].items():
            with open(path_to_includes+i+'.txt', 'w') as f:
                includes_to_write = n['includes'] 
                for line in includes_to_write:
                    f.write(line+'\n')
            f.close()
```